# Bottom margin width correct only if paragraph concludes at end of a page

Tags: margins, document-classes

I am using the biom.cls class to create a LaTeX document (http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/biom.cls.txt).

My preamble is simple:

```
\documentclass[referee]{biom}
\def\bSig\mathbf{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\VS}{V\&S}
\newcommand{\tr}{\mbox{tr}}
\title[My title]{My title}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
```

I am trying to ensure that all margins are about 1 inch. It seems to work for the left, top, and right margins. However, the bottom margin only seems to be about 1 inch if a paragraph ends exactly at the bottom of the page. Otherwise, if it is in the middle of a sentence, then the margin at the bottom of the page seems much smaller (it appears to squeeze in an extra line to the page).

I have tried adding different items to the preamble like:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead]{geometry}
```

But this really messes up the document by causing items to write over each other (probably by interacting with the biom.cls file strangely). Moreover, it does not appear to enforce a 1 inch margin at the bottom of the page still.

I am thinking I may need to update the biom.cls file directly to enforce 1 inch margins at the bottom. I have tried using marginbottom commands, but this too does not seem to work.

Any ideas on how to enforce the 1 inch margin with this type of setup? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: changing the margins for a journal supplied class is a _very_ odd thing to do, would such a document be accepted by International Biometric Society?

Comment: That's a good point. I am submitting this to a paper competition that    asks to use the style of the Biometric Journal (which uses biom.cls). However, it also asks that margins be kept at 1 inch. So, I am feeling stuck how to tweak the biom.cls format to force the bottom margin to be 1 inch.

Comment: I had a quick look at the class and it fixes `\textheight ` but does nothing else much so any use of geometry package or simply setting \textheight should have an effect. it would be rather hard to make the space after a paragraph differ from other cases assuming the paragraph is marked in the usual way (a blank line)  so as you have supplied no example hard to suggest what to change.